# Conenct Talend with Snowflake cloud

Tags: connection, talend, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new using Talend and Snowflake cloud.

I am trying to conet Talend using the component "Snowflake Connection", and complete with this settings:

```
user:XXX
password: YYY
Schema: TPCH_SF1
Database: SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA
```

and give me this error: `.net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Incorrect username or password was specified`.

But this user I can enter in Snowflake.

[image]

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Error clearly says your user name/ password is incorrect. If you have any issue with the connection, you will get connection related issues

Comment: Double-check username/password works via UI. Then make sure you are on the latest version of Talend and double-check the account name parameter in the Talend component is the full account name.  You can find examples of the full account name by region in the drop-down here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-log-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing it. Just to clarify different component what error comes through i have written down all different error come when which component throws error.

1. If snowflake account is wrong
   `java.lang.RuntimeException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: HTTP status=403.Incorrect Snowflake Account was specified`
   For this error we need to change the account name
2. Snowflake Region is wrong for valid snowflake account. **403 error is thrown**
   something like below.

   "`ERROR [main, net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil:logResponseDetails:449] -- Response content: 403 ERROR` "

you can define region name in Advance setting by checking in use Custom Snowflake Region for connection.

3. Snowflake username or password is incorrect for the account.
   `JDBC driver not able to connect to Snowflake. Error code: 390100, Message: Incorrect username or password was specified..`
   Hope this helps.